# Excel: repeat the same formula in a column by a given number expressed in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do something that may not be possible.
I am not a complete noob with Excel formulas, but close enough!
I have been looking for solutions all afternoon and now i have almost given up.

I am basically trying to populate cells in a column with the same formula, but the number of cells in the columns should be defined by a number in another worksheet.

not entirely sure i explained myself correctly as my english is not 100% perfect, so please be gentle :)

EDIT for more info

I am basically making a spreadsheet that creates product codes and asset tags/serial numbers
the product code is on "sheet 1" and it is something like aa-aa-aa-aa and that is on "sheet 1" i also have the number of products
asset tags will in "sheet 2" and i have alrady figured out the process of that, but i would like to generate automatically a number of asset tags/serial numbers on "sheet 2" by the given number of products in "sheet 1"
i hope this is clearer now.
whether is a formula or VBA, anything goes

Comment: That doesn't sound like something that is possible with just formulas alone. The formulas have to be typed or copy/pasted in which means you would have to know that number. It would be possible with VBA though. Would have to have more information to help out on the VBA front though.

Comment: i have added more info to my original post

Comment: What would make it clearer is a data sample. A screenshot would be good, a workbook would be better. Use an ad-free file sharing service like OneDrive or DropBox to share a file and post the link here. There may be ways to do that with Power Query, but it might as well be that this can only be done with VBA, in which case you will need to get on the learning curve, because this site is not a free programming service.

Answer (score 1):

Using just formulas, you can have a formula that performs a calculation until a specific row is reached. Something along the lines of

```
=if(row()<='Other Sheet'!A1,C1*D1,"")
```

If this formula starts in row 1 and is copied down, it will only perform the multiplication of cells C and D if the row that the formula is in is less than the number in cell A1 on the other sheet.

This formula still needs to be filled down as far as the largest number that could ever be in A1 of the other sheet.

If you don't want to use this approach, you will need VBA.

Comment: i have added more info to the original post